# Dictonary as default class parameter is shared for all class instances, why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I was just playing around with python and stumbled upon something that confuses me.

Why does t1 and t2 in the code below share the same decision dictionary? I have to write

```
t1=Decision({},txt1="Test1",txt2="Response Test1")
```

instead of

```
t1=Decision(txt1="Test1",txt2="Response Test1")
```

for them to have one each. Why?

I use Python 2.7 if that is of any importance.

```
class Decision(object):
    def __init__(self,decisions={},txt1="",txt2=""):
        self.decisions=decisions
        self.txt1=txt1
        self.txt2=txt2
    def run(self):
        if len(self.decisions)>0:
            print self.txt1
            print self.txt2
            for i in self.decisions: print i + " - " + self.decisions[i][0]
            ans=""
            while True:
                ans=raw_input("Enter answer: ")
                if ans in self.decisions: break
            if self.decisions[ans][1] is not None: self.decisions[ans][1].run()


t1=Decision(txt1="Test1",txt2="Response Test1")
t2=Decision(txt1="Test2",txt2="Response Test2")    

t1.decisions["yes1"]=("Yes","t2")
t1.decisions["no1"]=("No","t3")

t2.decisions["yes2"]=("Yes","t3")
t2.decisions["no2"]=("No","t1")

print t1.decisions
<<<{'no2': ('No', 't1'), 'no1': ('No', 't3'), 'yes1': ('Yes', 't2'), 'yes2': ('Yes', 't3')}
print t2.decisions
<<<{'no2': ('No', 't1'), 'no1': ('No', 't3'), 'yes1': ('Yes', 't2'), 'yes2': ('Yes', 't3')}
```

By the way. I solved it by doing this:

```
class Decision(object):
    def __init__(self,decisions=None,txt1="",txt2=""):
        if decisions==None:self.decisions={}
        else:self.decisions=decisions
        ...
```

But I would like to know why. Easier to remember not to do it when I now why I shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Because the def(inition) line that creates the empty dict is evaluated at the time the method is *defined*, not the time the method is *called*.